# How to apply css to particular selected child in ivh-treeview?

Tags: css, angularjs, treeview

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div ivh-treeview="dTree"
         ivh-treeview-id-attribute="'uic'"
         ivh-treeview-use-checkboxes="false"
         ivh-treeview-on-click="my_tree_handler(ivhNode)">
    </div>
</div>
```

and function in controller class:

```
$scope.my_tree_handler = function (branch) {
    branch.style.color = "red"; // "branch" is an object by the way
};
```

I want to apply css styling features to particular selected item, but I don't know how to do that. Documentation of this plagin "ivh-treeview" is not that helpful

Comment: How was the documentation not helpful? Did it not work when you tried to follow it?

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried and errors, if any.

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Since it's your first post let me tell you the way it works: you **have** to post what you have tried. Please update your question so you'll get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

It would be very helpful if you filled us in on what you've tried or specifically how the ivh-treeview documentation is not clear. As one of the project maintainers I would love to know where our docs are falling short :).

Have you looked at the [templates and skins](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/docs/templates-and-skins.md) section of the docs? This directive supports a default set of classnames which you can use to style your tree. When that's not enough, as in your case, you may provide your own node templates for the directive to use. There are a number of examples which demonstrate how custom templates can be used to create more or less arbitrary tree views.

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/jaqosi/edit?html,css,js,output) where custom templates are used to apply different styles to selected vs non-selected nodes. In this case we're doing some fun ascii checkboxes but the general idea is the same: observe some node property to affect the node representation.